# jQuery to vanalli JS content rotator

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have a simple jQuery powered content rotator, pretty simple stuff, and I am in the process of converting it to vanilla JS (jQuery-less) code. I got to a point where I'm replacing the jQuery `removeClass` function with the vanilla JS version `classList.remove` which throws it off.

To see what I mean, it will be easier for me to link you to a JSfiddle instead of including the code in this post. In the Javascript section I have included the jQuery code commented out (to see how it should function, comment out the vanilla JS version and uncomment out the jQuery version, then compare functionality of both versions, you'll see the problem).

http://jsfiddle.net/tomblanchard/9mc3r/